# C# populate a textbox from listbox taken from JSON file data

Tags: c#, json, string, integer, listbox

I have a JSON file from my local folder:

**Shawn Milke.json**

```
{
  "FirstName": "Shawn",
  "LastName": "Milke",
  "Email": "shawn.milke@alesana.com",
  "TeamName": "Shawn Milke",
  "Password": "shawn123",
  "IsActive": "Yes",
  "UserId": 100
}
```

Here's the code in populating the listbox from JSON file:

```
private void ShowListViewNew()
{
    List<UserAccount> userAccounts = new List<UserAccount>();

    var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
    var outputDir = Path.Combine(dir, "Output");

    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(outputDir, "*.json"))
    {
        var text = File.ReadAllText(file);
        var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserAccount>(text);
        userAccounts.Add(model);
    }
    listBoxUsers.DataSource = userAccounts;
}
```

And here's also my code in populating the textboxes from the listbox selected:

```
private void listBoxUsers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var model = (UserAccount)listBoxUsers.SelectedItem;
    txtFirstName.Text = model.FirstName;
    txtLastName.Text = model.LastName;
    txtEmail.Text = model.Email;
    txtTeamName.Text = model.TeamName;
    txtPassword.Text = model.Password;
    if (model.IsActive== "Yes")
    {
        chkIsActive.Checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        chkIsActive.Checked = false;
    }
    txtUserId.Text = model.UserId;
}
```

Now my main problem is I want to know how I can convert it from int to string in this line of code

```
txtUserId.Text = model.UserId;
```

Because I usually do it this way:

```
UserId = int.Parse(txtUserId.Text)
```

Since now it's changed, I'm not sure on how I can convert it from int to string. Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: model.UserId.ToString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to do this.

1-) A Simple static method - or you may prefer extension method- can be a proper way of this for the future usings.

```
public static string ConvertIntToString (int TheInt32)
{
 return $"{TheInt32}";
}
```

Usage:

```
txtUserId.Text = ConvertIntToString(model.UserId);
```

2-) Or Simply Convert inline

```
txtUserId.Text = model.UserId.ToString();
```

or

```
txtUserId.Text = "" + model.UserId;
```

or

```
txtUserId.Text = $"{model.UserId}";
```

All usage types are valid. As a developer, This will be your choice with depending of which C# version you choosen to use in your project.